# Angular: Redirect to parent if child parameter id is not supplied

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, lazy-loading

I have two modules each with their own routing:

```
CarsModule

PassengersModule (Lazy Loaded)
```

Passenger is a child of car, and is accessed via a url:

```
https://localhost/cars/12/passengers/1
```

CarsModule and PassengersModule each have routes defined:

```
const routesCars: Routes = [
    {
        path: "cars/:id",
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: CarsContainerComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: "",
                redirectTo: "dashboard",
                pathMatch: "full",
            },
            {
                path: "dashboard",
                component: CarsDashboardPageComponent,
            },
            {
                path: "passengers",
                loadChildren: () =>
                    import("./passengers/passengers.module").then(
                        (m) => m.PassengersModule
                    ),
            },
        ],
    },
];

const routesPassenger: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        redirectTo: ?????
    },
    {
        path: ":pid",
        component: PassengerDashboardContainerComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: "",
                component: PassengerDashboardContainerComponent,
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

if someone navigates to a passenger with no pid:

```
http://localhost/cars/12/passengers
```

I want to redirect that url to the Parent Car url:

```
http://localhost/cars/12
```

I tried doing this in an empty component which is loaded on path: "", but it seems clunky. What is best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use guard for deciding if a route can be activated or not.

PassengerRoute.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class PassengerRouteGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, public router: Router) { }
  canActivate(): boolean {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      if (!params['pid']) {
        this.router.navigate(['/cars/']);
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    });
  }
}
```

PassengersModule.route.ts

```
import { PassengerRouteGuard} from './PassengerRoute.service';
const routesPassenger: Routes = [
{
    path: ":pid",
    canActivate: [PassengerRouteGuard],
    component: PassengerDashboardContainerComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: "",
            component: PassengerDashboardContainerComponent,
        },
    ],
},
];
```

[Reference](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate#canactivate)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this method, but I don't seem to get the parent id in the parameters.

I changed the constructor to remove the route and passed the ActivatedRouteSmapshot into the method as suggested in the docs:

    constructor(public router: Router) {}
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {

But either way I do it, the params array doesn't have the carId so I can't navigate back to the parent:

//Doesn't work, params doesn't contain ID:
this.router.navigate(["/cars/", route.params["id"]]);